# Jsoup how to parse html element containing certain attributes?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am working on parsing an html snippet and like to get all the elements containing certain attribute pattern. e.g this is the html snippet:

```
<select type=button style='display:none;' name='1st6044hpy' value='1ktx95yolw'>

<input type=hidden name='1st6044hpy' value='1ktx95yolw'>
```

Here i would like to get all the elements having name='' and value='' attributes. Is it possible to get the elements having certain attributes e.g name and value in the above given elements. I have searched a lot about it but did not get any help. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, it is possible ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Elements links = doc.getElementsContainingOwnText("name");

Comment: Elements links = doc.select("input[style=display:none;]");

Comment: Both of them are not giving me desired result sir.

Comment: but element is not button but input ....

Comment: Sorry, the code snippet given is just an example. I have tried it for input as well sir.

Comment: `input[name][value]` should return all input elements with both name and value attributes ...

Comment: The element could be of any type e.g it could be <select>, <input> or anything else.

Comment: I would like to search the element on the basis of name and value attributes.

Comment: If the element is having name or value attribute, it should turn up in parsing. No matter if it is <input>, <select> or something else sir.

Comment: Are you getting what i meant to say sir?

Comment: then you should read about css selectors ...

Comment: By using doc.select i am using css selectors. Am i right sir?

Comment: Please point me in the right direction sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, ugly short example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Attributes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Attributes().doStuff();
    }

    private void doStuff() {

        String body =
                "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"/add/bundle\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    <select data-keyname=\"fieldtype\" name='1st6044hpyAAA' value='1ktx95yolwAAA1'>\n" +
                        "        <option value=\"\">Field Type...</option>\n" +
                        "    </select>\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    <input type=\"checkbox\" data-keyname=\"required\" name=\"1st6044hpyBBB\" value=\"1ktx95yolwBBB1\"> Required\n" +
                        "</div>\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "</form>";


        Document jsoutp = Jsoup.parse(body, "UTF-8");

        Element root = jsoutp.select("form").get(0);
        //selects
        Elements selects = iterateElementType(root, "select");
        //inputs
        Elements inputs = iterateElementType(root, "input");
    }

    private Elements iterateElementType(Element root, String typeField) {
        Iterator<Element> iterator;
        Elements selects = root.select(typeField);
        iterator = selects.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element element = (Element) iterator.next();
            if (element.hasAttr("name"))
                System.out.println("[" + typeField + "]" + "name: " + element.attr("name"));
            if (element.hasAttr("value"))
                System.out.println("[" + typeField + "]" + "value: " + element.attr("value"));
        }
        return selects;
    }
}
```

Just ignore calling from `main(String[] args)`, look at `doStuff()` method.